# I got stuck animating this crank

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I got stuck animating this crank, I don't know how to use Inverse Kinematics
[image]

Comment: You provided nearly no information. Provide blend file and/or your armature settings and what you tried so far

Comment: You should watch some tutorials for IK then, this is a bit complicated to write whole answer, you need to make one part rotate and other parts will be affected by it

Answer (score 5):

Edit: This solution, which is a simplification of Eng Morph's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTy6XTuuyys), seems to work better:

[image]

Create a 4 bone armature:

[image]

Bone 2 is parented to bone 1. Bone 3 is parented to bone 4. Give bone 3 an *IK* constraint with bone 2 as *Target*. Select bone 4 in *Pose* mode and in the *Bone* panel > *Inverse Kinematics*, set *IK Stretch* to 1 and activate *Lock IK* on X and Y:

[image]

Comment: i got confused at the limit location step. when i follow your instruction, the bones go like crazy. i really need to understand this so please teach me. i will send you the blender file

Comment: yes please share your file, use https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: the file is too big. it's 130 MB!

Comment: this is the link : https://firestorage.jp/download/296266fe39f0c868418c0ab39456783536d2ce35b2wnps1pbqjwf1e00j2p

Comment: Ok so there was probably a problem of circular dependency, I've edited with another solution

Comment: i already tried it and it almost perfect except bone no. 4 scale is becoming bigger.

Comment: you don't have to care about bone 4, just create a bone that is parented to the tail of bone 4 and it will be the one that you'll use as parent of the object that is supposed to slide

Comment: i mean, the part that i parent to bone 4 is becoming bigger too.

Comment: For the bone that you'll create and that will be the child of bone 4, go into the Bone panel > Relations > Inherit Scale, choose None

Comment: dude, i finally can make it. haha i really happy. i just deparent the bone 4 . rather i use child of. so it move smoothly right now. thank you so much for helping me dude. can i follow you or something?

Comment: You can check my profile, I make tutorials but it's in french  ;)  maybe your question will inspire me a tuto btw, even though it's not a common case to create pistons